# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Referencing Class libraries like .Net Framework 4.5.1 and .Net Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I was trying out to refer class libraries .net framework 4.5.1 in Core 1.0 latest 2016 release.

In the project.json  "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "net451" ,"net452"] is been taken care and the following gets added as dependencies in project.json

```
"Core.Framework.Testing": {
      "target": "project"
    },
```

I see no errors in the references but in the class file, I can't access the namespace like using Core.Framework.Testing in the class files in the same core project.

Is there something which I am missing here ?

Could you help me on this ?